# Beginner in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  document.getElementById("alertme").onclick = function() {

    alert("hell with you");

  }

< /script>
```

```css
#circle {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(167, 10, 10, 0.595);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>JavaScrip!</title>

</head>

<body>

  <button id="alertme">Hello</button>


  <p id="para1">
    This is a test
  </p>
  <button id="alertp">Whats written</button>



  <p id="inco">this is</p>
  <button id="incomp">complete sentence</button>
  <p id="change">i hate it</p>
  <button id="changeMe">change it!</button>
  <div id="circle">
  </div>
  <button id="hide">hide circle!</button>
</body>

</html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css" type="text/css">
```

Hi , i am new to JavaScript. I was practicing some code and ironically my JavaScript function of simple alert didn't work. Please guide me in simple way.
PS: Html and CSS were piece of cake compared to JavaScript.
Thanks.

Comment: `link` should be put in the `head` element. Supposing there is no space between the `<` and `script` tag, you should put the `script` element after the `#alertme` element, otherwise JavaScript can't find the target element.

Comment: where does that `<script>` element go? because as you've shown it, it's not in your html file, so it's not going to ever trigger. With that said, if you're starting with javascript, don't use `alert()`, but use the `console.log()` function instead, and check for its output in the developer console instead. alert blocks the page thread, console.log does not, and with the dev console, you can live-debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct but u have not included the script in your code.

add your script in the head section or before closing the body

one more thing i want to point out is to place the style sheet in the header.

your working code on[`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ef74d35w/)

Comment: Thanks for using your time for my problem. Surprisingly my script only work if put in just before closing body tag. Why doesn't it work inside head tag like css?

Comment: your script might run before the creation of dom so js are prefered to be kept just before the closing body tag insuring all the doms are created.